# Is my pin understanding correct on the 2N3904?

Tags: transistors, pcb

I have the following in my circuit:

[image]

Am I right in understanding that the pins top to bottom are:

1/Emitter
2/Base
3/Collector

where the top square pin is Emitter, middle pin with red trace is the Base and the bottom pin would be the collector?

The datasheet is here:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/2N3904.pdf

Many thanks!

Comment: Um, where's the link to the datasheet and what does it say? You have no pin numbers on the PCB so presumably 1 is the square pad but which order are the other two?

Comment: Added the datasheet

Comment: @RenegadeAndy you added the datasheet literally a few seconds before I posted my answer! I have linked a different datasheet, but it is the same component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your pinout. If you look at the [DATASHEET](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF), then you can see which pins are what.

[image]

Luckily, you have your silkscreen showing where the 'flat' side of the transistor should be facing. Using that, and the picture from the datasheet, you can see that the top of your screenshot), you have pin 1, then 2, then 3.

Checking this on the Datasheet, it is indeed Emitter, Base, Collector.

Comment: Some folks erroneously assume that all flat-sided transistors have similar pinouts. A few are CBE, others (Asian?) are BCE. Haven't seen any such deviations on 3904 from various makers. (2222 types DO have variations).

Comment: 2222 types may have variations (I didn't know that!) because the "real" 2N2222 calls out a metal package, not a TO-92, so any plastic "2222" is, at best, a 2222 die in a non-standard package.  I have certainly seen variations on the usual pinouts -- at least in the case of a few RF types I've run across it's clearly been for layout considerations (putting the emitter in the middle gives better isolation for a common-emitter circuit, for example).